# Unable to render RGB frames in openGL using textures

Tags: opengl, rendering, rgb

I'm trying to render a set of 200 RGB frames. For doing the same i'm creating a texture of height 416 and width 240.  However i just get a black screen with the print statements working in the background.

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "glew.h"
#include "glfw.h"
#include "glaux.h"

int index;
AUX_RGBImageRec texture1;
GLuint  texture;
unsigned long long pos;
unsigned char *guibuffer;
HDC hDC = NULL;

void initGL(void)
{
        int maxSz;
        int maxwidth = 416;
        int maxheight = 240;

        if( !glfwInit() )
        {
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }


        // if( !glfwOpenWindow(4096, 2118, 0,0,0,0,0,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
        if( !glfwOpenWindow(maxwidth, maxheight, 0,0,0,0,0,0, GLFW_WINDOW  ) ) //GLFW_FULLSCREEN
        {
            glfwTerminate();
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        glfwSetWindowTitle("sample");
               glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE,&maxSz);

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);       // This Will Clear The Background Color To Black
        glClearDepth(1.0);                          // Enables Clearing Of The Depth Buffer
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);                       // The Type Of Depth Test To Do
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                    // Enables Depth Testing
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                    // Enables Smooth Color Shading


        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        //glLoadIdentity();



        hDC= wglGetCurrentDC();
#if 1
        { // TSS
            HWND hCurrentWindow = GetActiveWindow();
            char szTitle[256]="sample";
            //SetWindowText(hCurrentWindow,szTitle );
            // SetWindowLongA (hCurrentWindow , GWL_STYLE, (GetWindowLongA (hCurrentWindow , GWL_STYLE) & ~(WS_CAPTION)));
            SetWindowLongA (hCurrentWindow, GWL_STYLE, (WS_VISIBLE));
        }
#endif

        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

}

int GL_Disply()
{
    FILE *fptr=fopen("E:\\myRGB.rgb","rb");
    fseek(fptr,pos,SEEK_SET);
    fread(guibuffer,sizeof(unsigned char),sizeof(unsigned char)*416*240*3,fptr);
    pos+=416*240*3;
    texture1.sizeX =416;
    texture1.sizeY =240;
    texture1.data = guibuffer;

    glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, texture1.sizeX, texture1.sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    //glNormal3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);

    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_BLEND); 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Swap front and back rendering buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers();
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initGL(); // GL initialization

    /* CPU memory allocation using C - malloc */
    guibuffer=(unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*416*240*3);

    for(index=0;index<200;index++)
    {
                printf("frame %d displayed....\r",index);
        GL_Disply();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Seeing all that deprecated code, hurts...

Comment: @Vallentin: Hi, as i hav already specified i'm a newbie in openGL. So i would request you to specify which are the functions that are depreciated?

Comment: These are the deprecated functions which you're using `glMatrixMode()`, `glLoadIdentity()`, `glTranslate()`, `glRotate()`, `glBegin()`, `glEnd()`, `glVertex()`, `glTexCoord`, `glNormal` ... of course when I write `glTexCoord` it goes for all the functions, `glTexCoord1f`, `glTexCoord2f`, etc ... also the `GL_LIGHTING` is deprecated as well as the functions used in `GL_LIGHTING`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing **data** (last parameter) to the [glTexImage2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) function. I guess you would want to pass data readed from your **E:\myRGB.rgb** file.

Comment: @sam: Also you shouldn't load and reload the texture data each and every frame. Technically almoast everything from `initGL` belongs into the drawing functions `everything except the `glfw…`calls (and that strange low level Win32 hack to set the... visibility and title? GLFW got ready to use functions for that – get rid of that code). But the whole texture loading stuff better belongs into the `initGL` code.

Comment: @datenwolf: Thanks for the suggestion, i shall implement it in my code. But i have a query. You say the whole texture loading stuff has to be in initGL, but each loop i fetcha new frame, so How shall i reflect the same?

Answer (score -1):

It may have something to do with the matrix stack.  I think you want to be in glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW) when you draw stuff, not GL_PROJECTION, and you may need to set up your matrices correctly.  Though, glMatrixMode, glBegin, glEnd, glTexCoord, glVertex3f, is the old fixed function way of rendering.  Using shaders is the modern way of rendering with OpenGL.